# Where to store images for android app?

Tags: java, android, download, storage, display

I'm creating a android application for Tourists. In that application user will be able to take photo and send them to storage. Other users will be able to display this photos on their devices. My question what kind of storage I have to choose to only display that photos without downloading them ?

Answer (score 0):

If one person takes the picture and another can view it on another device, it means you will have a server involved. This means you'll need to download a version of the image (even just a low quality version of it as cache) or you cant view it. Check out firebase ->[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)<- quite handy & well documented to do this kinda thing